# plm regression fixed effects on two variables,

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I have the following simplified df:

```
problem <- data.frame(
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                fkeycompany = c("0000001961",
                                "0000003570","0000003570","0000003570",
                                "0000003570","0000003570","0000003570",
                                "0000003570","0000004187","0000004187","0000004187",
                                "0000004187","0000016058","0000022872",
                                "0000022872","0000022872","0000022872","0000024071",
                                "0000050471","0000052971","0000052971",
                                "0000056679","0000058592","0000058592","0000058592",
                                "0000063330","0000099047","0000099047",
                                "0000099047","0000316206","0000316537",
                                "0000319697","0000351917","0000351917","0000351917",
                                "0000356037","0000356037","0000356037",
                                "0000700815","0000700815","0000700815","0000700815",
                                "0000704415","0000704415","0000704415",
                                "0000705003","0000720154","0000720154","0000720154",
                                "0000720154"),
                 fiscalyear = c(2018,2002,
                                2002,2004,2006,2007,2007,2014,2005,2005,
                                2009,2017,2003,2002,2004,2004,2010,2002,
                                2016,2008,2008,2002,2005,2005,2010,2014,
                                2000,2005,2005,2002,2002,2001,2005,2005,
                                2006,2007,2012,2015,2006,2006,2007,2008,
                                2003,2014,2014,2000,2004,2006,2008,2013),
           zmijewskiscore = c(-0.295998372490631,-3.0604522838509,-3.0604522838509,
                                -9.70437199970406,-0.836774487816746,
                                0.500903351523752,0.500903351523752,-1.29210741224579,
                                -1.96529713996165,-1.96529713996165,
                                -1.60831783946871,-2.12343231229296,-3.99767761748961,
                                0.561261861396196,4.13793269655047,4.13793269655047,
                                5.61803398400963,-0.000195582736436772,
                                -3.93766039340527,-0.540037039625719,
                                -0.540037039625719,-1.93767533120689,-4.54446419505987,
                                -4.54446419505987,1.94389244672183,
                                0.941272649148121,-3.88427264672157,-0.342812414189714,
                                -0.342812414189714,-1.35074505582686,
                                -4.52746658422071,-0.130671284507204,-0.223517713694019,
                                -0.223517713694019,0.0149617517859735,
                                -2.95100357094774,-2.55146691134187,-1.86846592111008,
                                2.92283100206773,2.92283100206773,
                                4.65325023636937,6.1585365469118,-4.54449586848866,
                                -1.49969162335521,-1.49969162335521,-3.34071706450412,
                                -1.72382101559976,-1.53076052307727,
                                -1.77582320023177,-1.57280701642882),
           lloss = c(0,1,1,1,1,
                     1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,
                     1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,
                     1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0),
  GCO_prev = c(1,1,1,0,0,
               0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,
               0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
               0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  GCO = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
          0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  industry = c(9,5,5,5,5,
               5,5,5,6,6,6,6,9,9,9,9,9,6,9,6,6,
               9,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,8,9,5,5,5,9,9,
               9,6,6,6,6,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9))
```

I would like to run a plm regression on this with fixed effects on year and industry.

```
library(plm)
summary(plm(GCO ~ GCO_prev + lloss + zmijewskiscore, index=c("fiscalyear", "industry"), data=problem, model="within" ))
```

However, I get this error while running:

```
Error in pdim.default(index[[1L]], index[[2L]]) : 
  duplicate couples (id-time)
In addition: Warning message:
In pdata.frame(data, index) :
  duplicate couples (id-time) in resulting pdata.frame
 to find out which, use, e.g., table(index(your_pdataframe), useNA = "ifany")
```

I do not quite know how to fix this. If I am assuming correctly, it has something to do with there being more companies (`fkeycompany` code) than 1 that have for example for `industry` = 9, `fiscalyear` = 2003 for example. So for some industries, lets say 9, there are more rows (fkeycompanies, in this example 0000016058 & 0000704415) which contain the year 2003 (or at least, thats what I think is the issue, or am I wrong?). This is with more industries and years the issue I believe in my main dataset. How do I fix this error message?

Also, besides this issue, is the code correctly that I am running? Am I indeed regressing with year and industry effects?

Comment: These seem to be statistical questions and not specific programming questions. This would be a better fit on [stats.se] where statistical questions are on topic. Your problems seems to be in understanding model assumptions and specifying the correct model for your hypothesis.

Comment: plm requires that you have a time series for each individual and a time series is a function of time, not a map from time to multiple values.  You could aggregate the input data so that for each individual there is only one row for each year and then work with the aggregated data.

Answer (score 0):

Given your data, the observational unit for panel data is firms (`fkeycompany`). You might want to add the industry as another fixed effect, but it cetainly is not the time index (the time index goes into the 2nd slot of argument `index` and I will assume it is `fiscalyear`). There are plenty of questions with answers to the topic. Also, do read the packages first vignette where the data specification for the `index` argument is explained.

I suggest to convert to pdata.frame first.

However, there are double constellations of fkeycompany and fiscal year, see below code where the output of `table` with a value > 1 hints you to the combinations.

```
library(plm)
pdat.problem <- pdata.frame(problem, index = c("fkeycompany", "fiscalyear"))
#> Warning in pdata.frame(problem, index = c("fkeycompany", "fiscalyear")): duplicate couples (id-time) in resulting pdata.frame
#>  to find out which, use, e.g., table(index(your_pdataframe), useNA = "ifany")
table(index(pdat.problem), useNA = "ifany")
#>             fiscalyear
#> fkeycompany  2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2012 2013
#>   0000001961    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000003570    0    0    2    0    1    0    1    2    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000004187    0    0    0    0    0    2    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
#>   0000016058    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000022872    0    0    1    0    2    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
#>   0000024071    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000050471    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000052971    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    2    0    0    0    0
#>   0000056679    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000058592    0    0    0    0    0    2    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
#>   0000063330    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000099047    1    0    0    0    0    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000316206    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000316537    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000319697    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000351917    0    0    0    0    0    2    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000356037    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0
#>   0000700815    0    0    0    0    0    0    2    1    1    0    0    0    0
#>   0000704415    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000705003    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000720154    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    1
#>             fiscalyear
#> fkeycompany  2014 2015 2016 2017 2018
#>   0000001961    0    0    0    0    1
#>   0000003570    1    0    0    0    0
#>   0000004187    0    0    0    1    0
#>   0000016058    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000022872    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000024071    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000050471    0    0    1    0    0
#>   0000052971    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000056679    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000058592    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000063330    1    0    0    0    0
#>   0000099047    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000316206    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000316537    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000319697    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000351917    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000356037    0    1    0    0    0
#>   0000700815    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000704415    2    0    0    0    0
#>   0000705003    0    0    0    0    0
#>   0000720154    0    0    0    0    0
```

Once fixed, you will be able to run a model along these lines.
For a time-fixed-effects model:

```
model <- plm(GCO ~ GCO_prev + lloss + zmijewskiscore, data = pdat.problem, model="within", effect = "time")
```

Or time-fixed-effects with `industry` as an additional fixed effect:

```
model2 <- plm(GCO ~ GCO_prev + lloss + zmijewskiscore + factor(industry), data = pdat.problem, model="within", effect = "time")
```